# what did jenkins actually build?

Tags: jenkins

I created a freestyle project in jenkins, in which I chose source code management as git, screenshot below

[image]

That's pretty my config. The repo you see in there is public repo. then I save the config, then I click build now.

[image]

It seems to works base on the notification on screen, which says 'success'. But I have no idea I what the heck Jenkins produced. I didn't instruct what to build and how to build. How does it know what I want? And lets say it did build something, where does it store the build? I didn't instruct it where to store the built file either. Can someone explain what is going on?

Comment: Build executes your defined actions, which is only the checkout. That's a success. Lookup a tutorial how to setup your project: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jenkins/jenkins_setup_build_jobs.htm

Comment: Currently, it is not building your code. It is just taking checkout of the code only which is successful. If have to define how to build your project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To actually build something you need to add something to your **Build** section in the project configuration.  For a javascript configuration it might look something like:

```
npm install
npm run test-coverage
npm run linter
npm run complexity
```

where each item after **run** is a script in your package.json.  Then you can add plugins to read the outputs of those actions, for example:

- Clover test coverage publisher
- TAP (Test) results publisher
- HTML Publisher for publishing static analysis results
- Checkstyle publisher for linting results

This allows you to pass and fail builds based on certain test criteria and where continuous integration starts to shine.

Answer (score 0):

In Jenkins job you have several sections - you can define pre build actions to prepare the environment, SCM to check out from source control, Build section to run your build pipeline and post build operation to run actions after the build section.

If you defined only the SCM section all your job did is to check out your sources from the source control you provided. the status of this action is SUCCESS.

Don't forget to check the console output of the job that ran to see which steps ran.